# Classification of isometry (and similarity transformation) in higher dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

As we know, bijective isometry between real normed spaces is affine (Mazur - Ulam 1932). Does there exist some closed forms or classifications of isometries in higher dimensional spaces like what we have in the Euclidean plane?

What about similarity transformations? Are they always affine between Euclidean spaces? Any universal classification in all dimensions?

Comment: Linear isometries possess a normal form: the space can be decomposed into invariant subspaces which are orthogonal, on one of which the map acts as the identity, on another, it acts as reflection and on all others, it acts like rotations.

Comment: Doesn't "real normed space" already include "higher dimensional spaces"? So you answered your question yourself? Anyway, an isometry in $\Bbb R^n$ is an orthogonal transformation plus a translation, always.

Comment: @M.Winter Thank you. I didn't realize it...